# What xls parser library is used in open office?

Tags: csv, xls, openoffice.org

What does open office use for importing xls files and csv files. Is it a library (or a body of code that can be easily packaged) that I could use in my project for importing xls and csv files? I'm building an analytics app and looking for a robust way to import xls and csv files.

Comment: It's open source. Why not try and look for yourself?

Comment: you are right, I'm being a bit lazy. I did look through their wiki that describes its code organization and it didn't help me. The task of navigating that humungous codebase without any guidance seemed daunting enough that I thought it might be more productive to ask someone who knows this code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this from dev@openoffice.apache.org:

For Microsoft formats, including XLS, a good option is Apache POI:

http://poi.apache.org/

And for ODF spreadsheet files as used in OpenOffice you can try the ODF Toolkit:

http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/